# Userform - Return to public sub from private sub

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have the below code which is a private sub which is initialized from Userform3.show in a public sub, as far as I am aware the code below works however it does not return to the public sub on completion.

Please note when I change the value of sheet8.range(I16) another private sub is called. However I believe the below code is the issue.

Can anyone advise how I can get the private sub to return to the public sub on completion?

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'populate "Combo-Box with Boards

With Me.ComboBox1
.Clear ' clear previous items (not to have "doubles")
.AddItem "BISSB"
.AddItem "MORIB"
.AddItem "RMIB"
End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
UserForm3.Hide
MsgBox "No board was selected, please re-run macro and select appropriate board"
Exit Sub

Else
Sheet8.Range("I16").Value = ComboBox1.Text

End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
UserForm3.Hide
MsgBox "No board was selected, please re-run macro and select appropriate board"
End
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
 If CloseMode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No board was selected, please re-run macro and select appropriate board"
    End
    End If
End Sub
```

Start of Public Sub

```
Sub newResumeAssessment_Click()
Dim answer As Variant
Dim Proceed As Boolean
Dim Uname As String

If UCase(Sheets("Main Menu").Range("A1")) = "YES" Then

answer = 6

Else

    answer = MsgBox("Click Yes to start a Business Case." & _
      vbCrLf & "Click No to resume the Business Case." & vbCrLf & _
      "Click Cancel to go back to the main menu." & vbNewLine & _
      vbNewLine & "Please note, you will need to load the board submission " & _
      "tracker before you start a new business case.", 35, "Business Case")

End If

If answer = 6 Then

UserForm3.Show
```

Comment: Get rid of `End`. That statement exits all procedures. There is almost never a reason to use it.

Comment: I have tried this - unfortunately it does not work and in the case of this code I have used *End* too ensure the public sub does not carry on if no drop downs are selected.

Comment: In which case, clearly removing it **does** work to return control to the public sub. Your public sub should then be checking to see if a value was selected.

Comment: Find another way to proceed then. For example, have a public Boolean variable which serves as a flag which the public sub can check when execution gets back to it. In the absence of `End`, execution always returns to the caller when the called sub finishes. I really don't know of a single instance in which `End` is necessary.

Comment: You should post the code that shows the Userform.

Comment: Your public Sub can read the values of controls on a hidden form, and then `Unload` it.

Comment: All I have updated so all the userforms code is present in the orginal post

Comment: Erm, what `Public Sub` are you talking about? Where's the code that *displays* the userform?

Comment: Unless you're showing a form non-modally, *the opening code always halts until the form is closed*.  maybe that's your problem?

Comment: I have included the start of the public sub also - Unsure what Non-modally "means"

Comment: Don't worry about it. Now that we see how the form is shown, we know it's modal (user can't click outside the form until it's closed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First thing**, remove `End`, everywhere. `End` is a big red NUKE 'EM ALL button that *ends* execution right there and then - after `End` has executed, it doesn't matter where you were in the call stack, for ***there is no call stack anymore***; your code isn't running anymore, there's nowhere to "return" to.

**Second thing**, don't keep state in the *default instance* of a form. Treat it like the object it is, and `New` up a new instance when you need one - that way you don't need to be bothered with `Unload`ing it and/or resetting the state between calls: the `_Initialize` handler will run every time, and there won't be a need to `Clear` the items from the previous call, since you'll be working with a fresh instance every time. You do that like this:

```
With New UserForm3 'UserForm_Initialize handler runs here
    .Show 'UserForm_Activate handler runs here
    'anything after .Show will only run after the form is closed
    If Not .Cancelled Then
        Sheet8.Range("I16").Value = .ComboBox1.Text
    End If
End With 'UserForm_Terminate handler runs here
```

Notice the worksheet is NOT being written to by the form - *it's not its job*! So how do we make that `Cancelled` member legal?

First you **name things** and make `CommandButton1` be `OkButton` and `CommandButton2` be `CancelButton` - or whatever - just not Button1 and Button2.

I like that you're *hiding* the form instance instead of nuking it with `Unload Me`, however you're *explicitly* working off the *default instance* again, which means the above `New UserForm3` code will not be hiding the same instance that's being shown. **NEVER** qualify member calls with a default instance when you mean to work with `Me`.

In other words:

```
UserForm3.Hide 'hides the default instance of UserForm3

Me.Hide 'hides whatever the current instance is

Hide 'same as Me.Hide
```

So. Add a `Private isCancelled As Boolean` private field (module-level variable), and then expose a `Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean` public property getter that returns it:

```
Option Explicit
Private isCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = isCancelled
End Property
```

Next, make your cancel button set the flag:

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    isCancelled = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Then make the `QueryClose` handler set it too - and use the existing named constants wherever possible:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        isCancelled = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub
```

Then implement your "happy-path" logic in the OK button's handler:

```
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

I would disable the OK button until the user makes a selection - that way they can either cancel, x-out, or make a valid selection!

```
Public Property Get SelectedBoard() As String
    SelectedBoard = IIf(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1, vbNullString, Me.ComboBox1.Text)
End Property

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ValidateForm
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateForm()
    Me.OkButton.Enabled = (SelectedBoard <> vbNullString)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ValidateForm
End Sub
```

And now the caller can look like this:

```
With New UserForm3
    .Show
    If Not .Cancelled Then
        Sheet8.Range("I16").Value = .SelectedBoard
    Else
        MsgBox "No board was selected, please re-run macro and select appropriate board"
    End If
End With
```

And now you have a form that's nothing more than an I/O device for your code, as it should be. And you're using objects instead of global state.

### TL;DR:

- Remove `End` instruction wherever they are.
- Don't reference `UserForm3` inside `UserForm3` (use `Me` instead).
- Work with a fresh `New` instance every time.
- Expose `Property Get` members for the calling code to access, to abstract away controls that the caller doesn't need to care about.
- Don't allow the form to be okayed in an invalid state.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! Your explanations has enhanced my VBA & Userform knowledge it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're showing a form non-modally, *the opening code always halts until the form is closed*