# Storing Variables from userforms VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I would like to save the ComboBox1 & ComboBox2 values as variables which I could use in the module I return to once the Userform is correctly completed by the user however I am unsure how to do this.

```
Option Explicit
Private isCancelled As Boolean


Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
Cancelled = isCancelled
End Property


Private Sub CancelButton1_Click()
isCancelled = True
Me.Hide
End Sub


Public Property Get Benefit() As String
Benefit = IIf(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1, vbNullString, Me.ComboBox1.Text)
End Property

Public Property Get Costdelivery() As String
Costdelivery = IIf(Me.ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1, vbNullString, Me.ComboBox2.Text)
End Property

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ValidateForm
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
ValidateForm
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateForm()
Me.Okbutton1.Enabled = (Benefit <> vbNullString And Costdelivery <> vbNullString)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
ValidateForm
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'populate "Combo-Box with Boards
With Me.ComboBox1
.Clear ' clear previous items (not to have "doubles")
.AddItem "Very High"
.AddItem "High"
.AddItem "Medium"
.AddItem "Low"
End With

With Me.ComboBox2
.Clear ' clear previous items (not to have "doubles")
.AddItem "Very High"
.AddItem "High"
.AddItem "Medium"
.AddItem "Low"
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Okbutton1_Click()

Dim Ben As Long
Ben = Me.ComboBox1.Value ***ERROR

Dim Cost As Long
Cost = Me.ComboBox2.Value **** ERROR

Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    isCancelled = True
    Me.Hide
   End If
End Sub
```

Ideally I would like to store the Low,Medium,High or Very high as values 9,10,11,12 as I will be using these as cell references in the module I return to after the userform is closed.

I understand I would need to state a public property my attempt which does not work is below;

```
Public Function ConfidenceChart()

Dim ben As Long, costd As Long

ben = UserForm4.ComboBox1.Text

If ben = "Low" Then ben = 9
If ben = "Medium" Then ben = 8
If ben = "High" Then ben = 7
If ben = "Very High" Then ben = 6

costd = UserForm4.ComboBox2.Text

If costd = "Low" Then costd = 12
If costd = "Medium" Then costd = 13
If costd = "High" Then costd = 14
If costd = "Very High" Then costd = 15

End Function
```

Comment: Declare some Public Variables on Standard Module and initialize them before the UserForm is unloaded.

Comment: I've edited my original post at an attempt at naming a public variable. Unfortunately I am relatively new too VBA - Consequently I am struggling to get it to work.

Comment: You can create a public method of the Userform (`ShowForm` for e.g.), which shows the form and returns values after form closed properly (hided, grabbed values, unloaded) or returns nothing if unloaded (closed by "X" for e.g). It's easy to implement without redundant public variables and  counts as proper OOP approach.

Comment: @CommonSense it's anything but a proper OOP approach. An object shouldn't be responsible for destroying itself (that's the job of whoever is creating that object), and should work regardless of how it's created - whether it's the default instance, a `With New UserForm1` block, or a caller-local new instance. Your approach would break 100% of my code. Forms *already* expose a `Show` method, don't you think adding a `ShowForm` method smells like some anti-pattern?

Comment: @sktneer OP's form is *already* exposing `Property Get` members for the values they're looking for. There's no need to add any public variables anywhere. The problem is that the comboboxes have no idea about the numeric values OP means to map to the selected text.

Comment: @CommonSense read OP's previous question, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453302/1188513)

Comment: @Mat's Mug, it's antipattern in `VBA` because there's no inheritance or overloading (or monkey-patching, you name it) on class level. Although it's don't break anything (or such cases are mystery for me) regardless how form is created, except case when form is modeless, because it counts on stopped codeflow.

Comment: @CommonSense this has absolutely nothing to do with lack of overloading and class inheritance, and everything to do with object lifetime - client is creating an object, it has all rights to expect to be able to access it until it no longer needs it. A self-destructing form that decides what happens with the user input is stepping on the caller's toes and responsible for too many things. See "smart UI" design [anti-]pattern, vs MVP and any other UI design pattern out there. VBA isn't to blame for stupid backwards code, only the coder is.

Comment: @Mat'sMug where I stated “self-destructed” form? Is form with “Quit” button, which executes “Call Unload(Me)” is self-destructed?

Comment: @CommonSense Yes, exactly that. `Unload Me` means it's not the caller running the show, it's the form - and *that* is the anti-pattern: a form is an I/O device, nothing more.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, ok, how user shoud close (generic) gui, if every possible option (even “x” is some sort of that) is self-destruction, hence anti-pattern. It’s doesnt point of question, but I’m curious about your opinion on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155615/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-commonsense).

Comment: @CommonSense sorry if I sounded annoyed - I've explained the reasoning in the chatroom link above; I just get irritated very fast when people start blaming the language for the wrong reasons. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ben` and `Cost` are *locals*, they're only visible from within the `Click` handler.

It's not the forms' job to know where these values need to end up - the form is only there to *collect user input*.

You *already* have `Benefit` and `CostDelivery` properties that the caller is able to access.

**Use them!**

```
With New UserForm1 'whatever the name of that form is
    .Show
    If Not .Cancelled Then
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = .Benefits
        Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = .CostDelivery
    End If
End With
```

If you need them to be numeric values, then you're not populating your comboboxes correctly.

Nowhere you're mapping `"Very High"` to `12`, the comboboxes only know about the strings.

To do that you need to change this:

```
With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear ' clear previous items (not to have "doubles")
    .AddItem "Very High"
    .AddItem "High"
    .AddItem "Medium"
    .AddItem "Low"    
End With
```

And assign `Me.ComboBox1.List` to a 2D array. Or a `Range`, if you have one that looks like this:

```
A          B
15         Very High
14         High
13         Medium 
12         Low
```

You could have a this helper method:

```
Private Sub PopulateFromRange(ByVal control As MSForms.ComboBox, ByVal source As Range, Optional ByVal valueColumn As Long = 1, Optional ByVal hasHeader As Boolean = True)
    With control
        .ColumnCount = source.Columns.Count
        .ColumnWidths = GetColumnWidths(source)
        .ListWidth = IIf(control.Width > source.Width, control.Width, source.Width)
        .List = source.Range(source.Rows(IIf(hasHeader, 2, 1)).EntireRow, source.Rows(source.Rows.Count).EntireRow).Value
        .BoundColumn = valueColumn
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetColumnWidths(ByVal source As Range) As String
    Dim cols As Long
    cols = source.Columns.Count

    Dim widths()
    ReDim widths(1 To cols)
    Dim col As Long
    For col = 1 To cols
        widths(col) = source(, col).Width
    Next
    GetColumnWidths = Join(widths, ",")
End Function
```

(taken from [this post specifically about populating combobox and listbox controls from ranges](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140995/23788))

And populate your comboboxes like this:

```
PopulateFromRange Me.ComboBox1, DataSheet.Range("A1:B5")
PopulateFromRange Me.ComboBox2, DataSheet.Range("D1:E5")
```

Assuming you have a `DataSheet` worksheet with ranges `[A1:B5]` and `[D1:E5]` respectively containing the text and corresponding numeric value for each item.

Comment: @SeanBailey oh, but I don't think I deserve the checkmark here - this answer is just a more complicated version of Thomas', which leverages the data binding capabilities of ComboBox controls to bind cells to it (whereas this code is "fire-and-forget", i.e. no bindings). Consider giving Thomas' answer the checkmark instead.

Comment: You could optimize `PopulateFromRange` by changing `source.Range(source.Rows(IIf(hasHeader, 2, 1)).EntireRow, source.Rows(source.Rows.Count).EntireRow)` to `IIf(hasHeader, Intersect(source.Offset(1), source).Value, source.Value)`

Answer (score 3):

Excel controls allow you to link controls to cells.  In this way, you can store the values of the controls for later use.

Userform controls use the `ControlSource` property to establish this link.  In my Demo below I create two named ranges on a setting page (named after the controls' names for easy reference) and set the controls `ControlSource` property to the named range.

[image]

[image]

### Addendum

@Mat'sMug pointed out that the OP needed to store a value from a lookup list base on the selection from a ComboBox.  This can also be achieved using named ranges.

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'populate "Combo-Box with Boards
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .RowSource = "List1"
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "0 pt;49.95 pt"
    End With

    With Me.ComboBox2
        .RowSource = "List2"
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "0 pt;49.95 pt"
    End With
End Sub
```

You will need to change some of the properties of the ComboBoxes.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'populate "Combo-Box with Boards
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .RowSource = "List1"
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "0 pt;49.95 pt"
        .ControlSource = "ComboBox1"
    End With

    With Me.ComboBox2
        .RowSource = "List2"
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "0 pt;49.95 pt"
        .ControlSource = "ComboBox2"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted, except this doesn't address OP's requirement of mapping the selected text values with underlying numerical values. It's very close though.